# Standard-Input to a command that is called with Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string `$command` which contains a program with its parameters, say

```
$command = "c:\mydir\myfoo.exe Parameter1 '/`$`$=bla' Parameter3".
```

I can run the command using Invoke-Expression:

```
Invoke-Expression $command
```

How can I redirect something to the standard input of the program? In my case, the program expects that the user enters some strings interactively like that:

```
v<RETURN>
<RETURN>
k01
<RETURN>
```

If I was working in the cmd.exe environment, I'd simply pipe my input strings to a file - say `d.inp` - and then start my program with this file as standard input:

```
c:\mydir\myfoo.exe Parameter1 /$$=bla Parameter3 < d.inp
```

(*)

How to do the same thing in PowerShell in an ideomatic way?

Thank you!

[*]
(Note that in cmd.exe, we do not need to escape the second parameter the way we had in PowerShell. This is not crucial in our case, but I remark it here for the sake of completeness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Start-Process` has a `-RedirectStandardInput`. You could see if it will work for your needs.